# Build failure when trying to build Particles/Standard Surface in Unity Particle Pack (Unity 2021.3.15f1)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just imported the [Unity Particle Pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/particles/particle-pack-127325) into a project I've been working on, and now the project refuses to build with the output

`Shader error in 'Particles/Standard Surface': Compiler timed out. This can happen with extremely complex shaders or when the processing resources are limited. Try overriding the timeout with UNITY_SHADER_COMPILER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MINUTES environment variable.`

- The project itself isn't too large, and building with the pack it takes around 10 seconds, so I don't think the timeout is the problem. I did try setting the timeout to 1 minute, and it still built as fast.
- I haven't changed anything in the pack from its defaults, and I've also tried importing the pack into a fresh Unity project, which built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think to do this until after I posted the question, but I updated to the current 2021 LTS version (2021.3.281f), not sure if I was actually running into a niche bug, or if the asset reimport is what fixed it, but it works now